# Specifying number of trials, bootstrap

Tags: r, machine-learning, mixture-model

For an assignment, I am applying mixture modeling with the mixtools package on R. When I try to figure out the optimal amount of components with bootstrap. I get the following error

```
Error in boot.comp(y, x, N = NULL, max.comp = 2, B = 5, sig = 0.05, arbmean = TRUE,  : 
Number of trials must be specified!
```

I found out that I have to fill an N: An n-vector of number of trials for the logistic regression type logisregmix. If
NULL, then N is an n-vector of 1s for binary logistic regression.

But, I don't know how to find out what the N is in fact to make my bootstrap working.

Link to my codes:
https://www.kaggle.com/blastchar/telco-customer-churn

My codes:

```
data <- read.csv("Desktop/WA_Fn-UseC_-Telco-Customer-Churn.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             na.strings = c("NA", "N/A", "Unknown*", "NULL", ".P"))
data <- droplevels(na.omit(data))
data <- data[c(1:5032),]
testdf <- data[c(5033:7032),]
data <- subset(data, select = -customerID)
set.seed(100)
library(plyr)
library(mixtools)
data$Churn <- revalue(data$Churn, c("Yes"=1, "No"=0))
y <- as.numeric(data$Churn)
x <- model.matrix(Churn ~ . , data = data)
x <- x[, -1] #remove intercept
x <-x[,-c(7, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21)] #multicollinearity


a <- boot.comp(y, x, N = NULL, max.comp = 2, B = 100,
           sig = 0.05, arbmean = TRUE, arbvar = TRUE,
           mix.type = "logisregmix", hist = TRUE)
```

Below there is more information about my predictors:

> dput(x[1:4,])
>   structure(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
>   34, 2, 45, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
>   0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 29.85, 56.95, 53.85, 42.3, 29.85, 1889.5, 108.15, 
>   1840.75), .Dim = c(4L, 23L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", 
>   "4"), c("genderMale", "SeniorCitizen", "PartnerYes", "DependentsYes", 
>   "tenure", "PhoneServiceYes", "MultipleLinesYes", "InternetServiceFiber optic", 
>   "InternetServiceNo", "OnlineSecurityYes", "OnlineBackupYes", 
>   "DeviceProtectionYes", "TechSupportYes", "StreamingTVYes", "StreamingMoviesYes", 
>   "ContractOne year", "ContractTwo year", "PaperlessBillingYes", 
>   "PaymentMethodCredit card (automatic)", "PaymentMethodElectronic check", 
>   "PaymentMethodMailed check", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges"
>   )))

My response variable is binary

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: Please post your *code*; see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the source code of `mixtools::boot.comp`, which is scary as it is over 800 lines long and in serious need of refactoring, the offending lines are:

```
 if (mix.type == "logisregmix") {
    if (is.null(N)) 
      stop("Number of trials must be specified!")
```

Despite what the documentation says, `N` must be specified.

Try to set it to a vector of 1s: `N = rep(1, length(y))` or `N = rep(1, nrow(x))`

In fact, if you look in `mixtools::logisregmixEM`, the internal function called by `boot.comp`, you'll see how `N` is set if `NULL`:

```
n <- length(y)
if (is.null(N)) {
   N = rep(1, n)
}
```

Too bad this is never reached if `N` is `NULL` since it stops with an error before. This is a bug.